# Creating 3 spinners that are populated by sqlite database

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I am trying to implement an activity, that has 3 spinners (drop down lists) each of which are populated by a different table from an sqlite database. I managed to create one spinner that is populated correctly, but i am having trouble creating the other two and populating them correctly.

this is my main activity so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {
private DBManager data;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final String DB_NAME = "hanakolfein.s3db";
private Spinner spinner;
List<String> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      /*Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;
        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
        sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(null); */

    data = new DBManager(this, DB_NAME);
    db = data.openDataBase();


    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    loadSpinner();
}

private void loadSpinner() {
    Set<String> set = data.getAllData();


    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setWillNotDraw(false);
}               


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }
}
```

and this is my database manager:

public class DBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
//Path to the device folder with databases
public static String DB_PATH;

//Database file name
public static String DB_NAME;
public SQLiteDatabase database;
public final Context context;
public final static int DB_VERSION = 6;

 public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
    return database;
}

 public DBManager(Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
 //full path to the databases
 String packageName = context.getPackageName();
 DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
 DB_NAME = databaseName;
 openDataBase();
}

 //This piece of code will create a database if it’s not yet created
public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
            throw new Error("Error copying database!");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
    }
}


//Performing a database existence check
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
    try {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
    }
    //Android doesn’t like resource leaks, everything should 
    // be closed
    if (checkDb != null) {
        checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb != null;
}

//Method for copying the database
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    //Open a stream for reading from our ready-made database
    //The stream source is located in the assets
    InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

     //Path to the created empty database on your Android device
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

     //Now create a stream for writing the database byte by byte
    OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

     //Copying the database
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    //Don’t forget to close the streams
    localDbStream.close();
    externalDbStream.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    if (database == null) {
        createDataBase();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    return database;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
public Set<String> getAllData() {
      Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
      String selectQuery = "select * from cuisine";
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
       set.add(cursor.getString(1));
       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }
      cursor.close();
      db.close();
      return set;
     }



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}




}
```

Comment: "_i am having trouble creating the other two_" You should explain in more detail exactly what troubles you are having.

Comment: well to create the first one, i used the getAllData inside the loadSpinner to populate it, in the other two, do i create 2 more getAllData that has the different queries? Do i create another loadSpinner? I am not sure how to proceed @Takendarkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear that arraylist which you pass to arrayadapter. Because when you use first spinner, you are calling gatAllData & storing that data in arraylist, passing it to arrayadapter. Next time for second spinner you are doing same procedure but it is concatenating to previous entries of arraylist. So before calling to getAllData you need to clear your arraylist. It'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, first of all you should not query your database from the main Thread.

I recommend using a Loader as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html). You can have as many Loaders as you like, in your case 1 for each Spinner (just make sure to give them different IDs).